# How to transfer a File from Java client to Java sever?

Tags: java, web-services, architecture, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

I need to give to a java client a way to send files to another application running in an Application Server. I don't need to process the file, but do some actions when the file is received.

What good ways to implement this communication are there?

I can think about EJB, but I'm not sure this to be the best option since i don't need the picture in memory, the same for WebServices...

Another option could be to open an FTP server but I wonder if there is a good alternative to do this with Java.

Any ocurrences or suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: What restrictions do you have?

Comment: You can read chunks from the Inputstream and write them immediately to disk, no need to have the entire file in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend [Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty) The documentation is great, it's simple to implement, and you can send anything through your own custom pipe that you need. Plus they have pre-built helper classes to just send files and do some pre/post processing work on both the client and server.

Comment: Great option, even if this question does not follow a "good/wrong answer" schema, I upvote all the good answers and choose this one as a way to reward that it has been the one I liked the more, because I didn't know about the existence of Netty. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I discovered it a while back and found it was the best of the options. Apache also has a similar system, but I found it more confusing and the documentation to be not as good.

Answer (score 4):

You could upload the file to a Servlet, e.g. using the [MultiPartEntity](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntity.html) of [Apache HTTPClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) in a POST request.

Comment: And on the server side, use [Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/) to handle the data.

Answer (score 1):

If you use EJBs, you're using RMI. You could try using [RMIIO](http://openhms.sourceforge.net/rmiio/) to stream the data. I've never used it, but it claims to do exactly what you want. It's pretty old, but then RMI is stable, so it should work fine.